# Como acessar elementos de um vector de um tipo definido por struct?

Tags: c++, struct, vector

No meu código, fiz a seguinte declaração de struct:

```
struct material {
    int idmaterial;
    double rho;
    double precokg;
};
```

Eu queria rodar essa função, que lê os dados de um arquivo:

```
std::vector<material> le_material(std::string s)
{
    std::ifstream dados(s);
    dados.exceptions(std::ios::failbit |
            std::ios::badbit);

    int N{0};
    bool fim;
    std::vector<material> infomaterial;
    fim = dados.eof();

    while (fim == 0) {
        dados >> infomaterial[N].idmaterial;
        dados >> infomaterial[N].rho;
        dados >> infomaterial[N].precokg;
        N++;
        fim = dados.eof();
    }

    return infomaterial;
}
```

Nesse arquivo, cujo nome é dado como parâmetro da função, há as informações de cada material. Em cada linha há 3 números, com os dados a serem lidos.

Entretanto, ao rodar o código e executar essa função na main, dá falha de segmentação.

Pelo o que consegui explorar, o erro se dá no momento em que se tenta passar os dados do arquivo para um elemento do vetor do tipo "material". Cheguei a achar que era um erro na leitura do arquivo, mas se eu tento ler algo que eu mesmo insiro no terminal, apesar de ser possível a inserção do valor, também ocorre a falha de segmentação, logo após a inserção.

Acredito que o erro deve ser na forma como estou tentando acessar um elemento do vetor, mas pesquisando sobre não consegui achar nada muito esclarecedor.

Comment: Provavelmente, você precisa alocar o espaço no vetor antes de utilizá-lo, tipo: `std::vector<material> infomaterial(10);` (para 10 elementos), ou inserir cada elemento com [*insert*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

Comment: Ah, é isso mesmo, obrigado!

Achei que era mais complicado do que isso, mas agora consegui fazendo a leitura assim:

1) Declaro uma variável do tipo material, mat_lido.

2) No while, faço a leitura assim:

  dados >> mat_lido.idmaterial;
  dados >> mat_lido.rho;
  dados >> mat_lido.precokg;
  infomateriais.push_back(mat_lido);

Agora estou tendo problemas com o momento em que o programa deve finalizar a leitura, mas estou criando outro tópico sobre isso.

Answer (score 1):

O erro de falha de segmentação acontece ao tentar alterar dados do vetor *infomaterial* sem inicializá-lo com elementos (o vetor está "vazio").

A solução é inicializar o vetor com um número pré-determinado de elementos:

```
// Exemplo para 100 elementos
std::vector<material> infomaterial(100);
```

Ou utilizar, por exemplo, o método [*insert*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) ou [*push_back*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) antes de ler um elemento do arquivo:

```
material m = { 0, 0.0, 0.0 }; // Declara um elemento 'default'
fim = dados.eof();

while (!fim) {
  infomaterial.push_back(m); // Insere um novo elemento antes de ler os dados
  dados >> infomaterial[N].idmaterial;
  std::cout << infomaterial[N].idmaterial << std::endl;
...
```